# Basic question on intra-assignment delay in Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, logic-gates, system-verilog

The Verilog intra assignment delay does not seem to work as I wanted. I am trying to model an OR gate with an output delay of 2 NS.
**Design:**

```
module or_gate(input a, b, output logic g);
  always@(*) begin
    g = #2 a | b;
  end  
endmodule
```

**Testbench:**

```
module tb;
  reg a, b;
  wire g;
  or_gate g1(.*);
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars(1, tb);
    $display("\t\tTime\tA\tB\tG");
    $monitor("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d", $time, a,b,g);
    a = 1'b1;
    b = 1'b1;
    #5;
    a = 1'b0;
    b = 1'b0;
    #1;
    a = 1'b1;
    b = 1'b1;
    #7;
    a = 1'b1;
    b = 1'b0;
    #3;
  end
endmodule
```

**Output**

```
Time    A   B   G
   0    1   1   x
   2    1   1   1
   5    0   0   1
   6    1   1   1
   7    1   1   0
   13   1   0   0
   15   1   0   1
```

I expect output to be 1, 2 NS after 7 NS, since inputs are 1 and 1 at 7 NS. However from 9 NS to 15 NS the output is 0. Why is this the case?

EDA Playground link of this simulation: https://edaplayground.com/x/tsqY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intra-assignment delays in a Verilog always block should NEVER be used (NEVER!). There is no known hardware that behaves like this intra-assignment delay using blocking assignments. If I could take this out of the Verilog language I would, but I can't because of backward compatibility. In Verilog training, I always say, "if your mother and I ever catch you putting delays on the right-hand side of a blocking assignment we will be very displeased!" (Once I bring "mother" into the recommendation engineers know that this is serious!)

The next question is, do you want to model inertial delays or transport delays? -OR- should you even be modeling with delays at all? Most RTL design is done with 0-delay modeling and then a Static timing Analysis (STA) tool is used to check the timing. Dynamic timing-based simulation is largely avoided except for Gate-Level Simulation (GLS).

I have a paper on my website from 1999 that answers all of these questions: Correct Methods For Adding Delays To Verilog Behavioral Models
http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsHDLCON1999_BehavioralDelays_Rev1_1.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This always block acts as a blocking one, so every time it enter the always block it will wait for 2ns before it could proceed further(in the meantime if any input is changing it will not cause any change in output like the one happening at 6ns).
So basically the expectation is the input should not change for a time less than the time consumed in always block, otherwise it will not be able to see the input change.

Please correct if this understanding is not right.

Comment: But input is stable for more than 2 NS, so why is it not propagated to the output?

Comment: It should not be stable, because always is triggered on a change in input value

Comment: It would have worked if there was a separate clock on which always block running,but here the always block is triggered by change in input, which is not happening

Answer (score 2):

At \$5\text{ns}\$, an event happens: \$11 \rightarrow 00\$, which triggers the `always` block.

The `always` block gets blocked for \$2\text{ns}\$, because of the delay statement. It is now blocked in the interval \$[5, 7\text{ns}]\$. So it misses the event at \$6\text{ns}\$: \$00 \rightarrow 11\$...

The output becomes \$0\$ at \$7\text{ns}\$. The `always` block gets unblocked. The missed events cannot be recalled so it could not trigger for the changed input: \$11\$ .... the output remains at \$0\$.

At \$13\text{ns}\$, an event happens: \$11 \rightarrow 10\$, which triggers the `always` block again and the output becomes \$1\$ at \$15\text{ns}\$.

Answer (score 2):

If we use non-blocking assignment instead of blocking assignment, the event will not be missed. Using blocking assignment blocks the simulation, and misses the event that takes place when the simulation is blocked.

**Design:**

```
module or_gate(input a, b, output logic g);
always@(*) begin
    g <= #2 a | b;
end
endmodule
```

**Testbench:**

```
module tb;
  reg a, b;
  wire g;
  or_gate g1(.*);
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars(1, tb);
    $display("\t\tTime\tA\tB\tG");
    $monitor("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d", $time, a,b,g);
    a = 1'b1;
    b = 1'b1;
    #5;
    a = 1'b0;
    b = 1'b0;
    #1;
    a = 1'b1;
    b = 1'b1;
    #7;
    a = 1'b1;
    b = 1'b0;
    #3;
  end
endmodule
```

**Output**:

```
                 Time   A   B   G
                     0  1   1   x
                     2  1   1   1
                     5  0   0   1
                     6  1   1   1
                     7  1   1   0
                     8  1   1   1
                    13  1   0   1
```

**Credits:**
The suggestion for using nonblocking assignment was given by Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange user and professional engineer [Rahul Behl](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/86595/rahul-behl).